# ReactJs TypeError: e._store.getters.options/getLinkExtsToSniff.indexOf is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I got this error: content.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e._store.getters.options/getLinkExtsToSniff.indexOf is not a function

I think it has something to do with the provider??

```
  return (
   <>
    <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} onError={onWalletError} autoConnect>
      <WalletDialogProvider>
        <Main voteAccount={voteAccount.account} />
      </WalletDialogProvider>
    </WalletProvider>
  </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I wrapped the provider inside <> and </>

After removing <> and </>, the error disappeared.